# Можно ли закрепить элемент за другим по ID

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Есть две таблицы, как я могу закрепить одну таблицу за другую? 
Пример:

```
<table id="Table1">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
</table>

<table id="Table2" style="behind-right:Table1">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: что значит _закрепить_?

Comment: Сделать так чтобы он был справа.

Comment: вы хотите вторую таблицу разместить справа от первой?

Comment: Да, но в будушем у меня будет много элементов раскиданных по странице и было бы круто если есть какая то фича по закреплению по ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Исправил**
Вот так - https://jsfiddle.net/yfsa8suu/

```css
.table-float {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-float">
<table id="table-1">
            <tr>
                <td>123</td>
                <td>123</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>123</td>
                <td>123</td>
            </tr>
</table>

<table id="table-2">
            <tr>
                <td>456</td>
                <td>456</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>456</td>
                <td>456</td>
            </tr>
</table>

<table id="table-3">
            <tr>
                <td>789</td>
                <td>789</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>789</td>
                <td>789</td>
            </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: сейчас переделаю)